# Failed to instantiate PooledConnectionFactory NoSuchMethodFound ActiveMq 5.8.0

Tags: java, jboss, activemq-classic

I have activemq 5.8.0 installed on JBoss fuse jms 1.1 is also insatlled commons pool 1.6 is also installed, the project that throws this error

`Application context refresh failed (OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext
(bundle=octopus-agency-nipost-service, config=osgibundle:/META-INF/spring/*.xml))`

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
    Failed to instantiate PooledConnectionFactory: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
    org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.<init>(org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory)
at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1326)
    [130:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:120)
    [137:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:283)
    [137:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)
    [106:org.springframework.context:3.1.3.RELEASE
```

The following dependencies are compiled with the project throwing the error above.

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId> 
    <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId> 
    <version>5.8.0.redhat-60024</version> 
</dependency> 

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
    <!-- lets use JMS 2.0 api but camel-jms still works with ActiveMQ 5.x that is JMS 1.1 only -->
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <version>5.8.0.redhat-60024</version>
</dependency>

<!-- xbean is required for ActiveMQ broker configuration in the spring xml file -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
    <artifactId>xbean-spring</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jms/jms -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms.local</groupId>
    <artifactId>jms-local</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You definitely have a version problem. I would try and change versions up or down to try to find where the method is implemented.

Comment: @JoaoEsperancinha yes I guessed as much and it may be from commons-pool version 1.6 but from research, it says 1.6 works with activemq 5.8.0. Do I raise both versions?

Comment: you need to keep trying or look into the API where this method is located and which library implements it. Googling it may help. In these situations one thing that comes to mind is to find out which method are you missing. Try to debug ObjectHelper.java:1326 and see what you can find there.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the version of your ActiveMQ and your dependency configuration in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
    <version>5.15.13</version>
</dependency>
```

verify if these are same.

[image]